# maven build fails in some environments, but then succeeds in a copy of the same directory

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I'm hoping that someone can offer some insight, some suggestions, or even just point me in a direction to try to solve this bizarre problem.

In some environments, such as our Jenkins server, and even sometimes on developer machines, if this one specific project is cloned from the git repo and then a maven build is run on it the build fails, prints a massive recursive stacktrace and throws a stackoverlow error.

```
$ git clone git@git@bitbucket.org:company/project.git
$ cd project
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
```

In situations where the build fails, if I make a copy of the project directory using "cp -r", and then run the build in that newly created directory... the build succeeds without any problems. (!)

```
$ cp -r project project_copy-r
$ cd project_copy-r
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Build succeeds with no errors>
```

If I make a copy of the project directory using "cp -a", and then run the maven build in the newly copied directory the build will fail with the same error as the original. (!!)

```
$ cp -a project project_copy-a
$ cd project_copy-a
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
```

If I make a copy of the project directory using "cp -rp", and then run the build in that newly created directory the build again fails with the same error.

```
$ cp -rp project project_copy-rp
$ cd project_copy-rp
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
```

So... something is different between the copy made with the "-a" or "-rp" flags versus the "-r" flag on the copy command.  The obvious choice here is that something in the project directory has overly restrictive permissions that get dropped when only using the "-r" flag.

However, if I run "sudo chmod -R 755 project_copy-rp" I still get the same build error.  Ditto if I then run "sudo chown -R me:me project_copy-rp"

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 project_copy-rp 
$ cd project_copy-rp
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
$
$ chown -R me:me ../project_copy-rp 
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
```

Furthermore, once the project folder has been copied using "-a" or "-rp" whatever problem is hiding in there appears to become 'locked-in' to the copy.  At this point re-copying the previously created directory using only the "-r" flag will not cause the build error to disappear.

```
$ cp -a project project_copy-a
$ cp -r project_copy-a project_copy-a-r
$ cd project_copy-a-r
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
$ <Fails with stacktrace seen below>
```

On the Jenkins server, the build is supposed to be done by a docker image containing Maven 3 and Oracle Java 8.  Once again the build fails with the same stacktrace.  To test the problem I git cloned a copy of the project to my home directory on the Jenkins server, installed Maven 3 and Oracle Java 8, and ran the build from there.  It succeeded without errors.

As I said - if anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it.

Stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default-compile) on project project-web: AJC compiler errors:
[ERROR] abort trouble in:
[ERROR] public class com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask extends java.lang.Object implements com.company.project.view.Task:
[ERROR] private final java.util.List rootNodes [Signature(Ljava/util/List<Lcom/company/project/view/tree/EvalTreeInputNode<TT;>;>;)]
[ERROR] private final com.google.common.base.Supplier rootNodeFactory [Signature(Lcom/google/common/base/Supplier<Lcom/google/common/base/Optional<Lcom/company/project/view/tree/EvalTreeInputNode<TT;>;>;>;)]
[ERROR] public void <init>(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Supplier)    org.aspectj.weaver.MethodDeclarationLineNumber: 18:587
[ERROR] :
[ERROR] ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 18)
[ERROR] INVOKESPECIAL java.lang.Object.<init> ()V
[ERROR] constructor-execution(void com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.<init>(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Supplier))
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 22)
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_1     // Ljava/util/List; rootNodes
[ERROR] | field-set(java.util.List com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes)
[ERROR] | |             PUTFIELD com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes Ljava/util/List;
[ERROR] | field-set(java.util.List com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes)
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 23)
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_2     // Lcom/google/common/base/Supplier; rootNodeFactory
[ERROR] | field-set(com.google.common.base.Supplier com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory)
[ERROR] | |             PUTFIELD com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory Lcom/google/common/base/Supplier;
[ERROR] | field-set(com.google.common.base.Supplier com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory)
[ERROR] |               RETURN   (line 24)
[ERROR] constructor-execution(void com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.<init>(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Supplier))
[ERROR] end public void <init>(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Supplier)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] public void execute(com.company.project.time.Time) throws java.lang.Exception    org.aspectj.weaver.MethodDeclarationLineNumber: 27:817
[ERROR] :
[ERROR] method-execution(void com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.execute(com.company.project.time.Time))
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 29)
[ERROR] | field-get(com.google.common.base.Supplier com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory)
[ERROR] | |             GETFIELD com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory Lcom/google/common/base/Supplier;
[ERROR] | field-get(com.google.common.base.Supplier com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodeFactory)
[ERROR] | method-call(java.lang.Object com.google.common.base.Supplier.get())
[ERROR] | |             INVOKEINTERFACE com.google.common.base.Supplier.get ()Ljava/lang/Object;
[ERROR] | method-call(java.lang.Object com.google.common.base.Supplier.get())
[ERROR] |               CHECKCAST com.google.common.base.Optional
[ERROR] |               ASTORE_2
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_2     // Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; optRootNode   (line 30)
[ERROR] | method-call(boolean com.google.common.base.Optional.isPresent())
[ERROR] | |             INVOKEVIRTUAL com.google.common.base.Optional.isPresent ()Z
[ERROR] | method-call(boolean com.google.common.base.Optional.isPresent())
[ERROR] |               IFEQ L0
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 32)
[ERROR] | field-get(java.util.List com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes)
[ERROR] | |             GETFIELD com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes Ljava/util/List;
[ERROR] | field-get(java.util.List com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes)
[ERROR] | method-call(void java.util.List.clear())
[ERROR] | |             INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.clear ()V
[ERROR] | method-call(void java.util.List.clear())
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_2     // Lcom/google/common/base/Optional; optRootNode   (line 33)
[ERROR] | method-call(java.lang.Object com.google.common.base.Optional.get())
[ERROR] | |             INVOKEVIRTUAL com.google.common.base.Optional.get ()Ljava/lang/Object;
[ERROR] | method-call(java.lang.Object com.google.common.base.Optional.get())
[ERROR] |               CHECKCAST com.company.project.view.tree.EvalTreeInputNode
[ERROR] |               ASTORE_3
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_3     // Lcom/company/project/view/tree/EvalTreeInputNode; rootNode   (line 34)
[ERROR] | method-call(void com.company.project.view.tree.EvalTreeInputNode.selectNode())
[ERROR] | |             INVOKEINTERFACE com.company.project.view.tree.EvalTreeInputNode.selectNode ()V
[ERROR] | method-call(void com.company.project.view.tree.EvalTreeInputNode.selectNode())
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_0     // Lcom/company/project/view/evaluation/EvaluationTagTreeInitTask; this   (line 35)
[ERROR] |               GETFIELD com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.rootNodes Ljava/util/List;
[ERROR] |               ALOAD_3     // Lcom/company/project/view/tree/EvalTreeInputNode; rootNode
[ERROR] |               INVOKEINTERFACE java.util.List.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
[ERROR] |               POP
[ERROR] |           L0: RETURN   (line 38)
[ERROR] method-execution(void com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask.execute(com.company.project.time.Time))
[ERROR] end public void execute(com.company.project.time.Time) throws java.lang.Exception
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] end public class com.company.project.view.evaluation.EvaluationTagTreeInitTask
[ERROR] -- (StackOverflowError) null
[ERROR] null
[ERROR] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERROR] at java.util.WeakHashMap.hash(WeakHashMap.java:298)
[ERROR] at java.util.WeakHashMap.get(WeakHashMap.java:396)
[ERROR] at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:2584)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World$TypeMap.get(World.java:1302)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:296)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:228)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.resolve(UnresolvedType.java:615)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getRawType(ResolvedType.java:2444)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:496)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:454)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeVariable.isASubtypeOf(TypeVariable.java:201)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeVariable.canBeBoundTo(TypeVariable.java:191)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:566)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:454)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:615)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:454)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeVariable.isASubtypeOf(TypeVariable.java:201)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeVariable.canBeBoundTo(TypeVariable.java:191)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:566)
```

The last 6 lines are repeated dozens of times until the end of the stacktrace.  The maven build appears to go into a recursive loop until the stack overflow occurs.

Comment: Have you already investigated the many, _many_, ***many*** hits in Google for `maven stackoverflowerror`?  Do any of them come close to matching your issue (other than the apparent randomness)?

Comment: Also, have you run a memory diagnostic on the machine?

Comment: I've looked at a lot of articles/questions regarding maven and stackoverflow errors, and haven't found anything that seems applicable. The error has popped up on 4 different machines, so I doubt a memory diagnostic on one of them would reveal anything.

Comment: Use a directory/file comparison tool to recursively compare the successful and failing directory trees, both before and after the build.  You'll have to wade through a lot of timestamp differences, but maybe you'll find something.  I was going to suggest WinMerge but I see you're on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You have a symbolic link somewhere that create a directory loop and you have a plugin that go over all your classes to do modifications (probably `aspectj-maven-plugin` here). The plugin is probably using some recursive algorithm to go over the directories, so because of the directory loop (which make it look like there is an infinite number of directories) it will reach stack overflow.

When you do `cp -r` you don't preserve the symbolic links, that's why it fix it, but both `cp -a` and `cp -rp` will preserve the links so you will continue to fail.

You should search for the symbolic links in your project, find the responsible and remove it.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, but unfortunately no, there are no symlinks in the project directory.

Comment: Strange, maybe you can check for setuid, setgid and sticky bit, that's the only other stuff that is affected by the flags you used for `cp` and that could affect this (see chmod man page for details).